# zoom with drag on bar not working using chartjs

Tags: javascript, charts, chart.js

I am trying to use chartjs and so far things were working out good. I included zoom plugin and saw some issues with zoom using drag not happening properly in some cases. Please see the code below. Try to zoom on 'x' axis using drag and you will see  that it wont happen. Please let me know how to fix this.

```js
        var randomScalingFactor = function() {
            return (Math.random() > 0.5 ? 1.0 : -1.0) * Math.round(Math.random() * 100);
        };

        var barChartData = {
            labels: ['January', 'February', 'March', 'April', 'May', 'June', 'July', 'August', 'September', 'October', 'November', 'December'],
            datasets: [{
                label: 'Dataset 1',
                backgroundColor: 'rgba(220,220,220,0.5)',
                data: [randomScalingFactor(), randomScalingFactor(), randomScalingFactor(), randomScalingFactor(), randomScalingFactor(), randomScalingFactor(), randomScalingFactor(), randomScalingFactor(), randomScalingFactor(), randomScalingFactor(), randomScalingFactor(), randomScalingFactor()]
            }, {
                hidden: false,
                label: 'Dataset 2',
                backgroundColor: 'rgba(255,187,205,1)',
                data: [randomScalingFactor(), randomScalingFactor(), randomScalingFactor(), randomScalingFactor(), randomScalingFactor(), randomScalingFactor(), randomScalingFactor()]
            }, {
                label: 'Dataset 3',
                backgroundColor: 'rgba(151,187,205,0.5)',
                data: [randomScalingFactor(), randomScalingFactor(), randomScalingFactor(), randomScalingFactor(), randomScalingFactor(), randomScalingFactor(), randomScalingFactor()]
            }]

        };

        window.onload = function() {
            var ctx = document.getElementById('canvas').getContext('2d');
            window.myBar = new window.Chart(ctx, {
                type: 'bar',
                data: barChartData,
                options: {
                    // Elements options apply to all of the options unless overridden in a dataset
                    // In this case, we are setting the border of each bar to be 2px wide and green
                    elements: {
                        rectangle: {
                            borderWidth: 2,
                            borderColor: 'rgb(0, 255, 0)',
                            borderSkipped: 'bottom'
                        }
                    },
                    responsive: true,
                    legend: {
                        position: 'top',
                    },
                    title: {
                        display: true,
                        text: 'Chart.js Bar Chart'
                    },
                    scales: {
                        xAxes: [{
                            ticks: {
                                min: 'February',
                                max: 'June'
                            }
                        }]
                    },
                    plugins: {
                        zoom: {
                            pan: {
                                //enabled: true,
                                mode: 'y'
                            },
                            zoom: {
                                enabled: true,
                drag: true,
                                mode: 'x'
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            });
        };
```

```css
    canvas {
        -moz-user-select: none;
        -webkit-user-select: none;
        -ms-user-select: none;
    }
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>

<head>
    <title>Bar Chart Zoom</title>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/chart.js@2.9.1"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/hammerjs@2.0.8"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/chartjs-plugin-zoom/0.7.7/chartjs-plugin-zoom.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
    <div id="container" style="width: 75%;">
        <canvas id="canvas"></canvas>
    </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: bro is this rectified? i also encountered this one. which version of chartjs are you using?